# Problems with Jumping Between Server and UI, also with combining Data Frames

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm trying to make a data analysis app for a project and am trying to allow for the capability to enter in new data sets. The only way that I could get it to work was to jump repeatedly between the server and the UI. I've run into a bunch of problems with that, but they aren't the main thing.

The main problem is in attempting to enter the new data into the old data frame. It keeps giving the *Warning: Error in data.frame: arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0* and sometimes the *Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero*

RStudio refuses to tell me where these are coming from so any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

All_Data <- data.frame(
  Name = as.character(c("2015 Acidobacteria C1")),
  Year = c(2015),
  Bacteria = as.factor(c("Acidobacteria")),
  Site = as.factor(c("C1")),
  Point_1 = as.numeric(c(5)),
  Point_2 = as.numeric(c(1)),
  Point_3 = as.numeric(c(8)),
  Point_4 = as.numeric(c(7)),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("ISAMR  Data Tool"),
        sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          #Make Boxplot Tool
                     h3("Boxplot Making Tool"),
                     numericInput("BPDS",h4("How many data sets to compare"), value=1, min=1,max=10),
          #Make Tool to add data
                     h3("Add Data"),
                     numericInput("NewDataNum", h4("How many points in data set?"), value = 1, min = 1, max = 4),
                     numericInput("NYear", h4("What Year is the Data From?"), value = 2020, min = 2000, max = NA),
                     selectInput("BactType",h4("Which type of Bacteria is it?"), choices = list("Acidobacteria", "Actinobacteria", "Alpha-Proteobacteria", "Bacteriodetes", "Verrucomicrobia")),
                     selectInput("NSite", h4("Which Site is it From?"), choices = list("C1","C2","C3","C5","C6")),
                     actionButton("DataReady", "Click When Ready"),
          #Make ANOVA Tool
                     h3("Run ANOVA"),
                     selectInput("OANOVA_1", h4("Choose Data to compare:"), choices = All_Data$Name),
                     selectInput("OANOVA_2", h4("With:"), choices = All_Data$Name)
             ),
        
        mainPanel(
          uiOutput("NewData"),
          uiOutput("AddData")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$NewData <- renderUI({
      try( 
        #Allow for different amounts of data entry
      if (input$DataReady >0){
            if (input$NewDataNum == 1){
                sidebarPanel(width = 20,
                textInput("P1",h4("Enter Point 1")),P2<-NA, P3<-NA,
                P4<-NA, actionButton("DataReady2","Click When Done"))
            }
            else if (input$NewDataNum == 2){
                sidebarPanel(width = 20,
                   textInput("P1",h4("Enter Point 1")),
                   textInput("P2",h4("Enter Point 2")),
                   P3<-NA,
                   P4<-NA,
                   actionButton("DataReady2","Click When Done")
                )}
            else if (input$NewDataNum == 3){
                sidebarPanel(width = 20,
                             textInput("P1",h4("Enter Point 1")),
                             textInput("P2",h4("Enter Point 2")),
                             textInput("P3",h4("Enter Point 3")),
                             P4<-NA,
                             actionButton("DataReady2","Click When Done")
                )
                }
            else if (input$NewDataNum == 4){
                sidebarPanel(width = 20,
                             textInput("P1",h4("Enter Point 1")),
                             textInput("P2",h4("Enter Point 2")),
                             textInput("P3",h4("Enter Point 3")),
                             textInput("P4",h4("Enter Point 4")),
                             actionButton("DataReady2","Click When Done")
                )}
        }, silent = TRUE)
    })
      output$AddData <- renderUI({
         
         if (input$DataReady2 > 0){
           # Combine factors into a title for the data set
           nname <- paste(input$NYEAR, input$BactType, input$NSite, sep = " ")
           # Add new row to the main data table with the new data
           All_Data %>% add_row(
              Name = as.character(c(nname)),
              Year = c(input$NYEAR),
              Bacteria = as.factor(c(input$BactType)),
              Site = as.factor(c(input$NSite)),
              Point_1 = as.numeric(c(input$P1)),
              Point_2 = as.numeric(c(input$P2)),
              Point_3 = as.numeric(c(input$P3)),
              Point_4 = as.numeric(c(input$P4))
          )
    }})

    
    
    }

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Each action button should have unique ID.  You are using same ID for four action buttons.  For example, `actionButton("DataReady2","Click When Done")` is repeated four times.